# Python Selenium не получается кликнуть по элементу в браузере

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Помогите пожалуйста. Написал код для того что бы открывался браузер и селениум делал некоторые клики в браузере.
Вот код элемента кнопки куда нежно нажать: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем что некоторые кнопки он нажимает а не кторые не хоче, если что пробовал через xpatch - не получается. Подкиньте идей пожалуйста

Мне нужно что бы селениум питон кликал на клавишу которая указана в коде элемента. Я пробовал уже через Xpatch, но почему то не нажимает. Просто запускается браузер и все. Код если что правильно у меня написан. Жду предложения как еще нажать на этот элемент

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно что бы селениум питон кликал на клавишу которая указана в коде элемента. Я пробовал уже через Xpatch, но почему то не нажимает. Просто запускается браузер и все. Код если что правильно у меня написан. Жду предложения как еще нажать на этот элемент